# Concat consecutive rows by grouping columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying something in Python to concat `ProdID` based on ProdCategory. All I need is last two columns `MainProdConcat` and `MainProdConcat_PCOnly`.

Let me know if its possible

```
OrderN0 ProdID  ProdCategory    ItemNo  ProdType    MainItem MainProdConcat MainProdConcat_PConly
123334  1   PC  100 Main    100 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
123334  2   PC  110 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
123334  3   PC  120 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
123334  4   PC  130 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
123334  5   Accessories 140 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 
123334  6   Accessories 150 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 
123334  7   PC  200 Main    200 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
123334  8   PC  210 Option  200 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
123334  9   PC  220 Option  200 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
123334  10  PC  240 Option  200 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
123334  11  Accessories 260 Option  200 7,8,9,10,11 

for index, row in df_OrderNo_WithBase.iterrows(): 
      orderid = row['Legacy Sales Order Identifier'] 
      dealid = row['Deal ID'] 
      df_Master.loc[(df_Master['OrderNo'] == orderid ) & (df_Master['Deal ID'] == dealid)),'ProductConcatMain'] = df_Master[(df_Master['OrderNo'] == orderid) & (df_Master['Deal ID'] == dealid) ]['ProdID'].str.cat(sep=',')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: for index, row in df_OrderNo_WithBase.iterrows():
    
    orderid = row['Legacy Sales Order Identifier']
    dealid = row['Deal ID']
    df_Master.loc[(df_Master['OrderNo'] == orderid ) & (df_Master['Deal ID'] == dealid)),'ProductConcatMain'] = df_Master[(df_Master['OrderNo'] == orderid)  & (df_Master['Deal ID'] == dealid) ]['ProdID'].str.cat(sep=',')

Comment: Example output?

Comment: as mentioned, i need last two columns to be calculated  MainProdConcat and MainProdConcat_PCOnly.

Comment: @EddyPronk can you share how? i

Comment: Please move your code out of the comment and into your question. That makes it much easier for us to read and you are more likely to get help that way.

Comment: @EddyPronk I guess this does technically answer OP's question...

Comment: done @BoarGules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input = '''
OrderN0 ProdID  ProdCategory    ItemNo  ProdType    MainItem MainProdConcat MainProdConcat_PConly
123334  1   PC  100 Main    100 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
123334  2   PC  110 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
123334  3   PC  120 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
123334  4   PC  130 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
123334  5   Accessories 140 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 
123334  6   Accessories 150 Option  100 1,2,3,4,5,6 
123334  7   PC  200 Main    200 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
123334  8   PC  210 Option  200 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
123334  9   PC  220 Option  200 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
123334  10  PC  240 Option  200 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
123334  11  Accessories 260 Option  200 7,8,9,10,11'''

from itertools import groupby

table = [x.split() for x in input.split("\n")]
heading = table[1]
data = [dict(zip(heading, x)) for x in table[2:]]

for x,y in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['MainItem']):
    y = list(y)
    MainProdConcat = ','.join([z['ProdID'] for z in y])
    MainProdConcat_PConly = ','.join([z['ProdID'] for z in y if z['ProdCategory'] == 'PC'])
    for t in y:
        print t['ProdID'], MainProdConcat,
        if t['ProdCategory'] == 'PC':
            print MainProdConcat_PConly
        else:
            print
```

Output:

```
1 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
2 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
3 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
4 1,2,3,4,5,6 1,2,3,4
5 1,2,3,4,5,6
6 1,2,3,4,5,6
7 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
8 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
9 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
10 7,8,9,10,11 7,8,9,10
11 7,8,9,10,11
```

Comment: i am not able to accept the answer. kindly mark this as completed

Comment: @radheradhe Would you be able to improve the question, so we can vote to re-open? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given print(df):

```
    OrderN0  ProdID ProdCategory  ItemNo ProdType  MainItem
0    123334       1           PC     100     Main       100
1    123334       2           PC     110   Option       100
2    123334       3           PC     120   Option       100
3    123334       4           PC     130   Option       100
4    123334       5  Accessories     140   Option       100
5    123334       6  Accessories     150   Option       100
6    123334       7           PC     200     Main       200
7    123334       8           PC     210   Option       200
8    123334       9           PC     220   Option       200
9    123334      10           PC     240   Option       200
10   123334      11  Accessories     260   Option       200
```

Then we can use these to populate 'MainProdConcat' and 'MainProdConcat_PConly':

```
df['MainProdConcat_PConly'] = (df[df.ProdCategory == 'PC']
                                 .groupby([df.ProdType.eq('Main').cumsum()])['ProdID']
                                 .transform(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))))

df['MainProdConcat'] = (df.groupby([df.ProdType.eq('Main').cumsum()])['ProdID']
                          .transform(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))))
```

Output print(df):

```
    OrderN0  ProdID ProdCategory  ItemNo ProdType  MainItem MainProdConcat_PConly MainProdConcat
0    123334       1           PC     100     Main       100               1,2,3,4    1,2,3,4,5,6
1    123334       2           PC     110   Option       100               1,2,3,4    1,2,3,4,5,6
2    123334       3           PC     120   Option       100               1,2,3,4    1,2,3,4,5,6
3    123334       4           PC     130   Option       100               1,2,3,4    1,2,3,4,5,6
4    123334       5  Accessories     140   Option       100                   NaN    1,2,3,4,5,6
5    123334       6  Accessories     150   Option       100                   NaN    1,2,3,4,5,6
6    123334       7           PC     200     Main       200              7,8,9,10    7,8,9,10,11
7    123334       8           PC     210   Option       200              7,8,9,10    7,8,9,10,11
8    123334       9           PC     220   Option       200              7,8,9,10    7,8,9,10,11
9    123334      10           PC     240   Option       200              7,8,9,10    7,8,9,10,11
10   123334      11  Accessories     260   Option       200                   NaN    7,8,9,10,11
```

Comment: Thanks so much. it works....